# How to check for a string is equivalent to a user input in Python?

Tags: python

I'd like to just read input from the user until a command is executed or a certain string is entered.

For example:

```
while "!finish" is not line:
    line = input(">")
    file.write(line+"\n")
```

I'd like to end the input if the user types in !finish and only that string. How can I go about doing this? Also, if there is a way to use key bindings, then that would be better.

Comment: Explanation for the downvotes please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be as simple as this, just be sure that line is defined before the loop

```
line = ''

while "!finish" != line:
    line = input(">")
    file.write(line+"\n")
```

Comment: From my experience, is not is only used when you're checking to see if a value is None. ie. if whatever is not None, it's a special use case scenario. Ignore me, listen to @ValekHalfHeart

Comment: `is` and `is not` don't compare type, they compare *identity*.  `2 is int` will return `False`, as it should; the integer object `2` is not the same as the `int` type.  `is None` and `is not None` are commonly used patterns because there's only one None instance.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: `is` and `is not` *do not* compare type! They compare identity. `1 is int` yields `False`. `[] is []` yields `False`. `a = []; a is a` yields `True`.